# Unit тесты для Service-слоя

Tags: java, база-данных, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте не так давно задался вопросом на тему того как тестировать сервис-слой в приложениях. Поискав немного информации в интернете нашел от одних, что нужно заводить тестовую БД и для нее писать UNIT - тесты. Другие в совю очередь сказали, что все делается на основной БД, но это мне не совсем понятно ведь должно же быть один тест = одному какому-тодействию( к примеру, если добавить пользователя в БД, его же надо будет потом удалить в этом же тесте, так как БД основная). К примеру взять вот мой код сервиса на Java(Spring Data), в качестве бибилиотеки для тестирвоания использую JUnit4.

```
@Service
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public boolean isExistUser(String login, String password) {
        User user = userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(login, password);
        return user != null;
    }

    public boolean removeUserByLogin(String login) {
        try {
            userRepository.deleteByLogin(login);
            return true;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public boolean addNewUser(String name, String login, String password) {
        try {
            User user = new User(name, login, password);
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
            return true;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы кто-нибудь либо показал пример как это правильно делается, либо очень подробно рассказал об этом процессе. Заранее спасибо...

Comment: Можно начать с просмотра роликов https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hBOIJfve2o и https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-eA9ZIkJBg

Comment: Сервисный слой тестировать можно и вовсе без базы, мокая репозитории. Если нужно протестировать именно взаимодействие с БД, то лучше использовать тестовую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такc, объясняю. Послойное тестирование приложение действительное классная штука, но вы здесь смешали понятия, говорите о тестировании слоя сервиса, а пишите про тестирование связки сервис-репозитори-бд.

Отвечая на вопрос "как тестировать сервис слой":
Вы должны замокать объект userRepository и тестировать объект сервиса в изоляции от слоя доступа к данным.

Например тест на метод getAllUsers мог бы выглядеть так (за точность синтаксиса не ручаюсь, пишу по памяти)

```
 public class UsersServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;

    @MockBean
    UserRepository userRepositoryMock;

    @Test
    public void getAllUsersTest(){
        List<User> usersFromMock=new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.doReturn(usersFromMock).when(userRepositoryMock.findAll());

        List<User> users = usersService.getAllUsers();

        Assert.assertEquals(users,usersFromMock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно в вашем случае, тестирование сервис слоя - это тоже самое, что тестирование слоя доступа к данным. Это значит, что вам необходимо настроить тестовую конфигурацию Hibernate, используя при этом IN_MEM базу данных, например  HSQLDB. В ней HIbernate (в большинстве случаев) сам воссоздаст структуру базы данных, использую Entity, или (для сложных сценариев) можно воспользоваться патчем для инициализации базы данных, который тоже указывается в настройках Hibernate.