# Как покрыть unit тестами void методы?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать?

Нужно написать unit тест на метод void который принимает коллекцию данных, для каждой записи коллекции формирует sql запрос в виде StringBuilder строки  и передает его на метод для выполнения в БД.

Как протестировать именно эти сформированные строки StringBuilder?

Что лучше использовать для решения такой задачи?

Comment: в бд, это в смысле напрямую в базу или в класс работающий с базой?

Comment: в метод другого класса, который отвечает за выполнение инсертов в базе.

Comment: Выделить формирование строки запроса в отдельный метод и его тестировать

Comment: не совсем понял, можно более подробно?

Comment: Это и есть метод  формирования строк запросов для каждой из записей в коллекции.

Comment: Ну так пусть от возвращает строку, а не воид

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я понял, некоторый void метод получает данные, потому делает из них строку и передает эту строку в другой метод этого же самого объекта?
В таком случае я бы сказал, что тестируемость данного построения когда слабая, но для решения подобных задач может помочь PowerMock.

Но лучше посмотреть в сторону рефакторинга кода, для лучшей тестируемости.

Comment: Строка передается в метод класса репозитория, который отвечает за сохранение в БД. Как я понимаю из всех комментов, лучший выход, это сделать рафакторинг.

Comment: В этом случае, с тестируемостью у вас все гораздо лучше (сложно было сразу понять как у вас устроен этот код). Раз у вас есть отдельный репозитори-объект, то для тестирования корректной генерации sql-запроса, вам нужно сделать следующее: 1) - Подменить объект репозитория моком (библиотека Mockito), 2) - Вызвать void-метод вашего тестируемого объекта 3) - Проверить что мок-объект был вызван с правильным параметром запроса (сгенерированной строкой)

Comment: Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/896127/313094)