# JUNIT тесты в многомодульном проекте Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Имеется Spring Boot многомодульное приложение, с настройкой бд через JNDI, как правильно запустить Junit тесты? Мой тест сейчас аннотирован так:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestServiceImplTest extends Assert {
```

Я создал файл application-test.properties, где прописал настройки для локальной бд, в исполняемом файле так же сделал @Bean DataSource с аннотацией @Profile("test") и при запуске теста получаю

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
```

Что я еще пропустил или может вообще делаю все неправильно?

Comment: Нужно проверить корректность настроек application-test.properties и зависимости

Comment: В вашем случае ошибка связана с профилем, который вы используете, на что вам уже указали. Однако советую подумать, стоит ли вам вообще полностью разворачивать все приложение, а это именно то, что происходит, когда вы используете SpringRunner. Для тестов сервис слоя совершенно не обязательно создавать соединение с базой данной, вы можете воспользоваться @Mock'ами и библиотекой Mockito в целом, чтобы имитировать эти соединения. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829202/unit-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-service-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

`application-test.properties` означает "использовать эти свойства, если запущено с профилем `test`"

`@Bean @Profile("test")` означает "создавать этот бин, если запущено с профилем `test`"

Ты запускаешь тесты с профилем `test`?

Надо в командную строку добавить `--spring.profiles.active=test`. Если используешь Мавен или Грэдл, то там есть свои способы задать свойство.